# Delete performance Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, sql-delete

I wanted to delete records from table A (it was about 14000 records). I created this query firstly:

```
DELETE (SELECT a.*
FROM A a
LEFT JOIN B b on b.ID = a.ID
WHERE b.ID IS NULL)
```

This took so much time that I had to stop after 1 hour. The inner query is fast.
Note that A has 5 tables that referencing it, but in those table the foreign key column has an index.

Then I tried this:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

BEGIN
  FOR rec in (SELECT a.*
              FROM A a
              LEFT JOIN B b on b.ID = a.ID
              WHERE b.ID IS NULL) loop

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('delete ' || rec.ID);
      DELETE FROM A WHERE ID = rec.ID;

  END LOOP;
END;
```

That has finished in about 5 sec.

Why is the loop faster then the first solution? I was thinking before that it should be the fast way, not the loop.

Comment: What about: `delete from a where not exists (select * from b where b.id = a.id)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name at the moment I cannot try because I have already commited

Comment: Are you sure something wasn't just blocking - i.e. locking one of the rows in A - during your first attempt, but had cleared by the time the PL/SQL version was run?

Comment: @AlexPoole I was thinking about that also. I tried the first one several times. Then I tried the second one. I rolled back and tried the first one, it was slow again. After that I run the second again. It was fast finished.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name your query is runnning fast also

Comment: @AlexPoole I created some data. The inner select statement retrieves 1 record only now. With the first way, I still have the same problem.

Comment: Nothing jumps out. Were there 14000 rows int he table, or were you deleting 14000 from a much large number? Are any of the FKs `on delete cascade`? Are there triggers? Is there partitioning? No idea why any of those would make this scale of difference, but some things to investigate maybe. Could also be a bug in your version of Oracle I suppose. Can only guess though I'm afraid.

Comment: Have you tried checking out the explain plan?